# Column getting deleted after Executing Macro in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba

I have written macro to import three columns from csv file to excel file which has 4 columns. 1 column is formulated based on 3 coming from csv file. So before running macro, there is excel file with 3 blank columns(not even column name) and 4th column with default values. Now when I run the macro, 3 columns are getting imported frm csv but 4th column is getting deleted.I don't know why this is happening. I have used Record Macro functionality to create macro. Below is my macro code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Sheet11.Cells.ClearContents
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;D:\Sample SSRS\power View\AlertHistory.csv", Destination:=Range("$A$1") _
        )
        .Name = "AlertHistory"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are clearing the entire worksheet with,

```
Sheet11.Cells.ClearContents
```

The 'default values' in the fourth column are going to be deleted along with everything else. If you only want to clear columns A through C and leave the 'default values' in column D then change that line to,

```
Sheet11.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 3).EntireColumn.ClearContents
```

This will not clear the entire worksheet; only columns A:C.